# How can I follow users using the instagram API without the limit rate issue?

Tags: php, api, instagram

I want to follow a list of user ids in instagram.
I made the list and when I try to send the follow request using the api, I get this error:
Client request limit reached (code: 400)

The developer documentation says: 
"You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id overall."

but when I get this error, my code hardly followed 50 user ids!

And one more thing, when I got this error I tried to follow people on the instagram app directy (not using the api) and there were no issues!

This is some part of my code that get's this error:

```
foreach ($usersArr as $user) {
$i++;
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user->id.'/relationship?access_token='. $accessToken;
$data = 'action=follow';
$resultObj = json_decode(sendPostData($url, $data));
$responseCode = $resultObj->meta->code;
$errorMsg = $resultObj->meta->error_message;
if ($responseCode != 200)
    echo "\"" . $errorMsg . "\" AT " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n\n";
while ($responseCode != 200){
    sleep(60);
    $resultObj = json_decode(sendPostData($url, $data));
    $responseCode = $resultObj->meta->code;
    if ($responseCode != 200) {
        $errorMsg = $resultObj->meta->error_message;
        echo "STILL \"" . $errorMsg . "\" AT " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n\n";
    }
    elseif($responseCode == 200){
        echo "Limit Finished At: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n\n";
        break;
    }
}
echo "User NO. " .$i . " has been followed!" . "\n\n";
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have gotten the same error in spite of not reaching the API limit. It seems that new apps may be penalized and not permitted to following users.

Comment: Do you have more than one app, try using the token, key from an other app and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @MetablocksCorp No I'm using the API with the CURL function in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the API is complaining about *requests*, not follows. You may be following 50 users but you have made API requests that exceed 5000. With your current code, it will only take 100 page refreshes for you to reach that limit. Might sound like a lot of refreshes but if you are debugging/developing code then it is plausible to assume that you could exceed the 100 refresh threshold with relative ease.

To mitigate this problem, if you are still working/debugging this code then reduce the number of follows from 50 to 1 or 2. Once your code is working then reinstate the previous number of follows. I would recommend you cache the return objects too, for 5 or 10 minutes. That way you won't need to worry about exceeding the API limits.

Comment: You are right, so now if possible I want to know how many people per hour I can follow so I can put a sleep(); function in my php code till the limit resets. I searched a lot in the documentation to learn how many follows per hour I can have, but no luck!
Also if there's a follow per day limit, I want to know :)
cause logically they shouldn't let users to overuse the api & they should've put a "per hour" & a "per day" limit for following...

Comment: You dont need to use sleep(), just make the request and cache it. Set the cache to expire after 5 minutes and once its expired make a new request and update the cache.

Answer (score 5):

My experience with the relationship endpoint of the API is that you are limited to around 160 requests per hour.  This appears to be shared with all the actions (follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/deny).  I have been unable to find anything that allows you to determine in advance how many requests you have left before you exceed your limit (unlike the X-Ratelimit-Remaining header in for the overall request limit), and I have noticed that a any attempt to use the endpoint is added to your request count, whether or not it succeeds.

Because my particular app is processing for multiple people concurrently, I process in small chunks (around 50 requests) and when I finish a chunk, or if I hit a rate limit within the chunk, I move on to another user for a while (typically around 10-15 minutes) before coming back.

I imagine the API limit is per-appid/clientkey, which is why you could follow users on the instagram  app despite reaching your limit.